# Nested Promise Array in Flatmap Not Recognized by TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Why is it that the following doesn't work:

```js
    async foo() {
        const x = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
        const y = [x, x, x];
        const z = (
            await Promise.all(
                y.flatMap(
                    a => Promise.all(
                        a.map(b => b)
                    )
                )
            )
        ).includes('a') // <-- Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string[]'.ts
    }
```

The following, however, works:

```js
    async foo() {
        const x = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
        const y = [x, x, x];
        const z = (
            await Promise.all(
                y.map(
                    a => Promise.all(
                        a.map(b => b)
                    )
                )
            )
        ).flat().includes('a')
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner Promise.all returns a Promise<string[]>.
The outer Promise.all receives an array of those array resolving promises, which means it resolves to array of arrays (string[][]). By flattening it you receive the simple array (string[]).

Comment: So, what's the difference between using `flatMap` before and using `flat` after `map`? Isn't the former just a way to do both in one go?

Comment: You use the flatMap on an already flattened array. The outer Promise.all creates the 2d-array, which is around the flatMap